# Count of matched terms

Tags: full-text-search, ravendb

I've had a look in a few different places and havn't been able to find an answer to this question. I'm hoping someone may have the answer here.

Is it possible when using ravendb, to include the amount of search terms matched in a query?

If I had some documents containing a list of strings with any combination of the values: "yellow", "blue", "red". 
Given the search term "yellow red", would it be possible to return results stating:

```
X records matched 2 terms.
Y records matched 1 term.
```

Thanks,

James

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with fragment highlighting.  (Newly added to RavenDB 2.0, under-documented at the moment.)  [Here is the overview](http://ayende.com/blog/160835/ravendb-new-feature-highlights).  The API changed slightly since then.  [Here is one place I've used this feature](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb.contrib/blob/master/src/Raven.Bundles.Contrib.Tests/IndexedAttachments/HighlightsWithIndexedAttachments.cs)

Comment: Ah excellent, i'll have a read into that. The test really helped to understand it.